# How to change colors of a Firemonkey TProgressBar in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey

The **TProgressBar** class doesn't have any color propriety and even if you edit the custom style you can see the vindicator (TStyleObject) which is representing the bar, but it doesn't have any color properties that can be changed.
Is it possible to change colors of a **Firemonkey TProgressBar** in **C++ Builder**?
Is it possible to create a custom style with custom colors for a **Firemonkey TProgressBar** in **C++ Builder**?
Is it possible to dynamically change this style at run-time?
Thank you for any response or suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

TStyleObject links to a bitmap which contains the image to display. The properties of interest are SourceLookup which contains the StyleName of a bitmap within the style, and SourceLink. This property contains links to regions of the bitmap to display.

The style designer should also have pulled the bitmap and if you look at it (hint: MultiResBitmap property) you should see the appropriate region(s) within it.

At this stage things begin to get complicated because there's no way I know of to export or edit the bitmap within the editor.

There are other ways to access the bitmap (e.g. the Bitmap Style Designer on the Tools menu) but if you want to change colours are run-time this probably won't help you. I would suggest rebuilding the style to use simple TRectangles. Just make sure you reuse the same StyleNames so the code can find them.

For a fixed colour create a fresh bitmap, add it to your style and reference it into the TStyleObjects.